# Copy constructor is generating an error when I try to call the super constructor

Tags: java, constructor

When writing the copy constructor for my class I get an error message, what am I doing wrong?

```
public class SaleItem extends Item {
double price;
double shippingCost;
int numItems;


public SaleItem(SaleItem toCopy){

    this.price = toCopy.price;
    this.shippingCost = toCopy.shippingCost;
    this.numItems = toCopy.numItems;
}
public SaleItem(String name, String description, double price, double shippingCost, int numItems){
   super(name, description);
    this.price = price;
    this.shippingCost= shippingCost;
    this.numItems = numItems;
}
```

Comment: isn't the problem that `super` is **not** being called? What is the error message?

Comment: _"I get an error message"_ - would be helpful if you post that error message too

Comment: When I call "super" as i did in the constructor below the error reads "name and description have private access in item"

Answer (score 1):

You should declare that attributes as `protected`, for instance:

```
public class Item {

    protected String description;
    protected String name;

    public Item(){}

    public Item(String description, String name){
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //Getter and setters...

}
```

Comment: ok, now the error im getting is " cannot reference 'item.name' and 'item.description'  before supertype constructor has been called."

Comment: That's because you're sending as name and description something that is being created, could you please edit your post and add how are you calling the `new SaleItem(...)` ? I've edited my post to show you how the Item constructors should be declared

Comment: Problem solved, I actually didnt change the fields in the item class to protected, all I did was the following...Super(toCopy);

Comment: Consider accepting and up voting if the answer was helpful.